# Testing scalability of Postgres Database

Tags: database, postgresql, benchmarking, ycsb, tpc

For my project built on Postgres, I want to check the system's scalability. Are there any standard database benchmarks suitable for it? I have gone through YCSB but could not get it to work with Postgres. TPC benchmarks do not really challenge scalability. My definition of scalability is based mainly on the different number of queries and not on the rate of it or the size of the Database.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html). It is included with PostgreSQL and comes with a TPC-B-like standard workload. You can scale the size of the database and the number of clients.

It is not a full-fledged benchmarking software, but it is surprisingly volatile, allows you to supply your own statements for your own database, has a little scripting language included and has a few other bells and whistles.

I guess it would do what your describe.